# Changing the button/link image on calling setResponsePage wicket

Tags: java, image, apache, button, wicket

So I do have my button in wicket, and I want to set him to one of two images, depending on one of the two conditions. In one condition the button should be disabled too.

```
private static final Image rwImage = new Image("rewindButton", new ContextRelativeResource("/images/rw.png"));
private static final Image rwImageGrey = new Image("rewindButton", new ContextRelativeResource("/images/rw_grey.png"));



AjaxFallbackLink rewindButton = new AjaxFallbackLink("rw") {

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

            // Sets page parameter to 0, and sets response page with a given page parameter.
            setResponsePage(MessageStorePage.class, new PageParameters().add("currentPageParameter", 0));
            //After calling above, currentPage=0;

        }

    };
    // rewindButton.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    // rewindButton.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
    // Displays grayed out and disabled button if current page is the first one.
    if (currentPage <= 0) {
        rewindButton.add(rwImageGrey);
        rewindButton.setEnabled(false);
    } else
        // Displays button if current page is not the first one.
        rewindButton.add(rwImage);
    // Adds "first page" button
    add(rewindButton);
```

Everything is cool, setEnabled works fine, but the button image is displayed randomly(wrong, not like I want). At launching it in incognito mode it works fine, so smth may be wrong with caching/cookies, dunno :/

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a special reason for using an ajax link when doing a redirect when clicking it? Maybe this is just a stripped-down example, but if not, I'd rather use a normal link implementation in this case, e.g. `Link` or `BookmarkablePageLink`.

Comment: No there is none, I needed it to be ajax before and thats why its this way, but still changing it to Link it would acomplish nothing with my problem - as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I think there are several solutions for your use case, depending on your needs... that's why I am asking. If you do not need pretty URLs, I'd rather let Wicket handle the page's state for me, e.g. having a field `int currentPage= 1;` in the page and changing the value `onClick`. If you actually need or want to pass it as an URL parameter, your example is missing the piece of code reading the page parameter to `currentPage`, which might well be the place where something is going wrong.

Comment: I need setResponsePage to reload whole page, because whole content depends on this one parameter

Comment: You meant why I use params instead of changing the currentPage manually and setting a response page without parameters?

Comment: From what I can currently see, I'd think it would be much more convenient to make use of the fact that wicket pages can be stateful, so that you can just store a value to a field in your page/component, so you would not need to think about request parameters yourself... have a look at this example: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.LinkPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Well, I got rid of the issue by adding:

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

To my html file.

May be a dirty solution, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's a caching issue because you replace the same image (the same id and all) with a different image either wicket or your browser doesn't grasp the fact that it's actually different. You should look at how the generated html differs.

I think explicitly disabling caching on the image might be a way to make it work.

Another quick-term solution might be to add both images to the link and make one of them invisible based on the context.

Comment: Another quick-term solution might be to add both images to the link and make one of them invisible based on the context.

I created additional button with another wicket ID, so now one is grey and another is normal, and I change their visibility, but it still sometimes displays grey image, for normal one ( and action is normal) and vice versa..

Comment: Please add the relevant code example. I suspect there's a bug where you forget to add the links to the ajaxrequest or the visibility gets reset by another piece of code but I can't tell without looking at your code. ;-)

Comment: I had  them done corectly :)
Already found partial solution tho :)